# PHP and Google Maps

Tags: php

After a lot of trial and error on trying to get google map's plot markers on a map after i have filtered a xml file i have found this to work. Problem i have is i need to change the URL inside the map HTML to show the specific number i initially filtered on the XML file

This is the the search string i have

```
<form action="control_lbsresult.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="query" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

It gives me the filter and the filter URL is as such

```
/control_lbsresult.php?query=0716747329
```

This is the snippet code that filters the XML file

```
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$msisdn = $_GET['msisdn'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM lbs_ WHERE msisdn='$msisdn' LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<lbs_>';
```

In the map html i have everything right but the file extension as per the bottom code needs assistance with

```
downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php?msisdn=0716747329", function(data)
```

If i save the number 0716747329 in the coding it works. What i need is a lookup that inserts the number after the msisdn=(****) bit but from the search screen us the number i entered.

```
downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php?msisdn='$msisdn'", function(data)
```

How do I insert the $msisdn here do I used $_GET or $_POST and how do i notify this page to look at the search input

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean but can it simply be:

```
downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php?msisdn=" . $_GET['msisdn'], function(data)
```

Do note that this is not safe, you should sanitize the $_GET['msisdn'] in your SQL query before you use it. Make sure it is a number.

Also, please use the PDO library for database queries instead of mysql_*.